Trying to load data from user selected json onto openlayers
I'm trying to write code that allows the user to select a json file and create a layer on top of the map in openlayers, the ability to allow the user to select the json file they want works and the json file itself is correct, the code I use to create the layer based off the json file is found below, however my friend who has solved this says that I'm not using the right function to load the data onto the layer.
I looked at info from https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134688/add-geojson-layer-to-openlayers-3, From API to vector layer openlayers JSON, and geojson itself and from the looks of it both seem to state that creating a Vectorsource and Vectorlayer then adding it using the addlayer function is how the data is loaded. I figure the readFeatures function is what allows VectorSource to read the features of the json file and addLayer was what loaded the data. I did also try using the vectorSource.addFeatures function as well but to no avail. I'm still reading up on all the API documentation but I don't see anything that seems to contradict the code I've been using.
    const vectorSource = new VectorSource({features: new GeoJSON().readFeatures(json, { featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857' }),});
    const vectorLayer = new VectorLayer({ source: vectorSource });

    // Add the vector layer to the map
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);`

***Update*** I'm not supposed to modify json file given, but as a test I created a basic point json file as below and the point shows up. Funnily enough however, if I change the coordinates to the json below then nothing shows up again (i.e [10, 5], [10,0], [0,10], etc). Also while actual json file we are supposed to use is more complex, I have confirmed that is not an issue as my friend was able to use it succesfully and we are not supposed to modify it.
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [0, 0]
        },
        "properties": {
          "name": "Test Point"
        }
      }
    ]
  }


Is the map view using 'EPSG:3857'?   Are you calling useGeographic()?

So I printed and it is using EPSG:4326, however when I do make the change in the featureprojection in VectorSource, I am still encountering the same issue, test point still works but actual json does nothing.

There must a setting somewhere else in you code causing the problem.  If I add more features with real coordinates to your test json they display correctly https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-6fdzkr?file=package.json,index.html,index.js

If you are working with data that is not in geoJSON format, you will have problems. The two coordinates of your example above are [0,0], and of course there will be no markers on the map

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
